# Have a script execute a command randomly every now and then

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app, bash-scripting, random-number-generator

I have a script which I am scheduling to run daily with Cron.  However I want a certain section of the script to only run randomly occasionally, with a certain probability of executing on any given day.

Here's my basic idea.

use $RANDOM and cut to get a single random digit:

```
echo $RANDOM | cut -c1
```

use an if/then test to evaluate this digit and execute only when it matches a certain value:

```
if [(echo $RANDOM | cut -c1) = 3]; then
echo "YES" >> ~/result.txt
fi
```

However, this is not working. The script fails with the following:

```
./testscript: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
./testscript: line 3: `if [(echo $RANDOM | cut -c1) = 3]; then'
```

I think the idea is sound, but I'm guessing I'm getting the syntax wrong.

Any ideas?

Using bash on Mac OSX 10.7.2

Possibly interesting sidenote:  I ran `echo $RANDOM | cut -c1` 100,000 times and then worked out the frequency with which each digit appears, so using this I can adjust the frequency with which the script executes by selecting the appropriate values.  Interestingly the distribution of digits at first glance seems to obey Benford's Law...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if [ "$(echo $RANDOM | cut -c1)" = 3 ]; then
    echo "YES" >> ~/result.txt
fi
```

or even

```
[ "${RANDOM:0:1}" = 3 ] && echo "YES" >> ~/result.txt
```

Comment: This works too!  Thank you for showing how it can be done other ways.  Selected this as my accepted answer because it fixes the way I was trying to do it, although the other answer provided also works.

Answer (score 3):

It's nicer to test if $RANDOM is smaller than a given number.  If you chose 10000,

```
if [ $RANDOM -le 10000 ]; then
    echo "YES" >> ~/result.txt 
fi
```

Will do the trick.  Of course you can pick a different number. ("-le" means less-than-or-equals).